# Dell Lattitude 5490, issue with keypad clicks with Debian 9

Tags: debian, xorg, dell-latitude, keypad

I have issue with keypad click. They do not work properly as my wired mouse.

When I use `xev` to identify wich key is sent :

- my wired mouse : left: Button1, right: 3 (good configuration)
- my keypad: left: Button3, right Button2 (wrong configuration)

The synclient output :

```
$ synclient 
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = 47
    RightEdge               = 1152
    TopEdge                 = 34
    BottomEdge              = 601
    FingerLow               = 25
    FingerHigh              = 30
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 59
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 75
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = 27
    HorizScrollDelta        = 27
    VertEdgeScroll          = 0
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 0
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 0
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.147493
    TouchpadOff             = 2
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 0
    RBCornerButton          = 0
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 0
    TapButton2              = 0                                                                                                                                                                                    
    TapButton3              = 0                                                                                                                                                                                    
    ClickFinger1            = 1                                                                                                                                                                                    
    ClickFinger2            = 0                                                                                                                                                                                    
    ClickFinger3            = 0                                                                                                                                                                                    
    CircularScrolling       = 0                                                                                                                                                                                    
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1                                                                                                                                                                                  
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0                                                                                                                                                                                    
    CircularPad             = 0                                                                                                                                                                                    
    PalmDetect              = 0                                                                                                                                                                                    
    PalmMinWidth            = 10                                                                                                                                                                                   
    PalmMinZ                = 200                                                                                                                                                                                  
    CoastingSpeed           = 20                                                                                                                                                                                   
    CoastingFriction        = 50                                                                                                                                                                                   
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 30                                                                                                                                                                                   
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 0
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
    HorizHysteresis         = 6
    VertHysteresis          = 6
    ClickPad                = 0
```

lspci:

```
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
        Region 0: Memory at ef252000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        Region 4: I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
        Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
        Kernel modules: i2c_i
```

xinput :

```
$ xinput 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard       id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL0816:00 044E:121F Touchpad            id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard       id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell Dell USB Entry Keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard       id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

What I have tried before to force `synaptic` :

```
apt remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput
apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
apt install xautomation
apt install xbindkeys
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xinput --set-button-map 15 2 1 3
```

Or play with changing the order of `2 1 3` for your demand.

Note: reinstalling is **never** a solution.

Comment: In my case, was  `xinput --set-button-map 15 2 3 1`, thanks !